# Programming ATTiny1614; Unexpected Signature

Tags: attiny

Trying to program an ATTTYIN1614 with jtag2updi.

```
https://github.com/ElTangas/jtag2updi
```

I was able to use this tool to program an ATTINY1626-XFR and ATTINY807-MNR, but I'm getting an error with ATTINY1614-SSFR.

```
avrdude: Expected signature for ATtiny1614 is 1E 94 22
         Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.
```

Comment: If you want to make the answer follow more from the question, the part of the avrdude output listing that shows the signature that was actual read would be helpful.

Comment: @EdHayes3 if you do not indent the URL, then it becomes clickable ... indented lines are formatted as code

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong ATTiny1614 selected. Needed to select the non-optiboot option.

[image]